# SWRevelViewController with iOS 9 Xcode 7

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, swift, swrevealviewcontroller

Im currently using on my app (build on iOS 7 target objective c) SWRevelViewController in a large storyBoard (20+ VC's).

I'd like to revamp my app and bring it up to date to iOS 9 and a new storyBoard.

Now i see SWRevelViewController hasn't been updated since 2013 (version 2.3) and after looking around i see even with newer Swift projects they still use SWRevelViewController in the tutorial.

I am aware of other alternatives to SWRevelViewController (MMDrawer and such).
My question is should i stay with SWRevelViewController and rebuilt the storyBoard with it or is there a better alternatives do note i have to use unWind segue in my app and i understand there is a bug with SWRevelViewController on the matter.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: I'm making an app with it now and it still seems good. I'm curious about the unwind segue issues you mention b/c I have several, and other custom segues I've added to my project and they all work pretty great together. I subclassed it and create a root UIViewController for it - that's where I unwind to.

Comment: Well i saw this link :

https://github.com/John-Lluch/SWRevealViewController/issues/543